# In JSF, what's the difference between from-view-id and from-tree-id?

Tags: java, jsf

In JSF, in a typical `faces-config.xml` configuration, what's exactly the difference between `from-view-id` and `from-tree-id` tag? And when was the best time to use either?

Any example would be much appreciated.

Comment: What JSF version is this (from the `faces-config.xml` header)?

Comment: It says version 1.0. I'm actually reading it on a tutorial and curious on what it means because I've been using only `from-view-id` during the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the `from-tree-id` element; I don't remember it from any previous JSF version.

The element doesn't appear in any of these schemas:

- `http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_0.dtd`
- `http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-facesconfig_1_1.dtd`
- `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd`
- `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd`

Check the element isn't in another namespace; it could just be a typo in the tutorial.

Comment: I believe you're right, McDowell. I've looked at the dtds and they didn't mention anything about `from-tree-id`. But I checked the tutorial again, and it's not a typo though I didn't read the whole tutorial to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to JSF 1.0 `<from-tree-id>` tag was used. But in JSF 1.0 this tag has been replaced by `<from-view-id>`.